# How To Add Ip Address manually in debian 12

Tags: iptables

I have two scripts that I can use to add block ip addresses to iptables.  So for a list of let's say 10,000 or more it takes forever.  Can I just copy and paste this block of ip address manually?  If so, where would I do it in Debian 12?

Comment: There has been a similar question over at ServerFault: ["iptables, blocking large numbers of IP Addresses"](https://serverfault.com/q/119937).

Comment: for i in {11..255} ; do  echo Deny from $i.0.0.0/8 ; done

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block a multitude of IP addresses, use `ipset` and the related iptables module.